# spring boot application.yml completely ignored(exists under target/classes)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-kafka

Running spring boot application as below:
My port `8080` is in use so I am trying to change it. Also, I deliberately am giving wrong bootstrap server for kafka to see if it takes effect.

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.config.location=file:/src/main/resources/application.yml,classpath:application.yml`

I verified that `application.yml` exists under the expected location and looks like below

```
~/Documents/springboot/codedecode25:=> cat target/classes/application.yml
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9093
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
  server:
    port: 9098
```

But notice the logs(pasting only parts of it), that the bootstrap server property is still being the default as 9092 and server/tomcat is starting at 8080 and application fails to launch.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.
```

During the start(pasting parts of logs to show it starts at 8080 and the kafka server port is still default)

```
edecode25)
2023-10-28 19:12:25.957  INFO 51238 --- [           main] c.c.KafkaDemo.KafkaDemoApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-10-28 19:12:26.808  INFO 51238 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-10-28 19:12:26.820  INFO 51238 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-10-28 19:12:26.820  INFO 51238 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2023-10-28 19:12:26.907  INFO 51238 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-10-28 19:12:26.907  INFO 51238 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 908 ms
2023-10-28 19:12:27.380  INFO 51238 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values:
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    check.crcs = true
```

Contents of pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.codedecode</groupId>
    <artifactId>KafkaDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>KafkaDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Kafka implementation</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>application.yml</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

Also, the application.yml does not even exist when I use intellij. Am I using some wrong annotations in my spring boot app?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`server.port` property is not belong to `spring`. Try to move it to the root of `application.yml` file.

```
server:
  port: 9098
```

Comment: Thanks, I had realized that just a few seconds ago and yes now the port is changed. However, the bootstrap server for kafka in reality is running at 9092 and though my properties file says 9093, it is getting ignored or might be possible that internally kafa lib first checks 9092 always?

Comment: So you want to force application stop if the bootstrap server is not available? Then try this `spring.kafka.admin.fail-fast`